# jQuery unwrap div within p

Tags: jquery

I'm building a CMS and have a WYSIWYG to enter text; but as formatting is passed over from another document, you sometimes get a random `<div>` copied over.

So, more often than not, the HTML output for some standard text will look like:

```
<div class="show-text">
    <p>In Italo Calvino’s 1985 novel Mr. Palomar, the reader is taken on a journey through mundane but highly individual musings, seen from the perspective of the title character, who takes his name from the famous telescope and observatory. Mr Palomar tries to explain and define his existence by seeking order and reason in his visual and cultural surroundings. Taking the novel as a starting point, this exhibition has developed through close collaboration and discussion between the artists to create a symbiosis between the artworks, the boundaries of which are at times ambiguous.</p>
    <p>Dylan Shipton’s work re-models the space through large-scale architectural interventions, including a viewing structure that provides an altered view of the other pieces. Shipton’s work will serve as an environmental framework and counter-point for the other works to react with and against. In an extension of her painting practice, Kate Brigden is showing a series of glazed porcelain objects that aim to toy with ideas of vision and perception, suggestive of cosmic concepts. Pippa Gatty’s video projections simulate a landscape and atmosphere, enveloping and interrupting the objects and structures.</p>
    <p>Palomar is developed from a project initiated at Surface Gallery, Nottingham 2012.</p>
    <p><div><em>‘In identifying a constellation, the decisive proof is to see how it answers&nbsp;</em><em>when you call it. More convincing than the matching of distances&nbsp;</em><em>and configurations with those marked on the chart is the reply that&nbsp;</em><em>the luminous dot gives to the name by which it has been called, its&nbsp;</em><em>promptness in responding to that sound, becoming one with it.’ &nbsp;—&nbsp;</em>Mr.&nbsp;Palomar, Italo Calvino, (Martin Secker &amp; Warburg, 1985)</div></p>
</div>
```

So, I'm curious to know, using jQuery, how I can unwrap any unwanted `<div>`s within the `<p>`s. I thought this would work:

```
$('.show-content-container .show-text p div').contents().unwrap();
```

But it simply removes the p before and after the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your markup looks to you:

```
<p><div>
```

[**How it looks to jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdGS8/) when testing with `.show-text.html()`:

```
<p></p><div>
```

Therefore that selector will never do as you wish as there aren't actually any div's inside any p's.

If you don't want any div's inside .show-text at all, you could just use:

```
$('.show-text').find('div').contents().unwrap();
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SdGS8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The div is not rendered in the `p`.

```
$('.show-text div').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>';
});
```