# Unwrap all paragraph tags inside the div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i have the sample html where i want to unwrap all paragraph tags inside the div.Currently html looks like this.

```
<div class="divclass">
   Hi this is some text. 
   <p>testing test</p>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Testing text2</a></p>
</div>
```

but i want like this.

```
<div class="divclass">
   Hi this is some text. 
   testing test
   <a href="#" rel="nofollow">Testing text2</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271884/jquery-unwrap-div-within-p

Comment: This can help too https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the contents of p elements:

```
$('div p').contents().unwrap();
```

However you have p element which do not have contents. such tags will not be removed with code. you need to find the siblings p and then remove it.:

```
$('div p').contents().unwrap().siblings('p').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jqotkqLL/)**

Comment: this only work for first paragraph tag inside the div.

Comment: @HassanRaza: check the fiddle. it unwraps all p element and removes empty p element as well

Comment: Good answer. Love it :)

Comment: @milind it works fine for me i mark it verified answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript (is faster than Jquery because it uses native code):

http://jsfiddle.net/ks60L4h9/3/

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

while(p.length) {
    var parent = p[ 0 ].parentNode;
    while( p[ 0 ].firstChild ) {
        parent.insertBefore(  p[ 0 ].firstChild, p[ 0 ] );
    }
     parent.removeChild( p[ 0 ] );
}
```

This selects all paragraphs, then uses .contents() to target the content of `<p>`, then `.unwrap()` to remove its parent `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
// unwrap p tags having content;
$('.divclass p').contents()// get content of all p tags
                .unwrap() // unwrap p tags
                .siblings('p:empty') // get all p siblings which are empty
                .remove(); // and finaaly remove it
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divclass">
   Hi this is some text. 
   <p>testing test</p>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Testing text2</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p></p>` wont be unwrapped as it have no contents

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below code :-

$('p').contents().unwrap();

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to use replaceWith(), which has less cost than unwrap().

It also works for empty tags.

```
$(".divclass p").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wyrou4t/